# Propagate nixpkgs checkout to NixOps machines

Tags: nix, nixos, nixops

I'm maintaining my personal changes on `nixpkgs`, which I use both for system rebuilds (via NixOps) and for development on my workstation (mostly via `nix-shell`). The changes are commits rebased ontop of the `nixos-17.09` channel and are stored on a private git server. All of the machines in the deployment have read access to that git server.

When using `nix-shell` on a remote machine, I get old packages originating from the install time of the machine (in my case `nixos-17.03`).

Is there any way to have the exact same revision of `nixpkgs` which is used for deployment available at the remote machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem your having is due to the fact that because NixOps builds locally and then copies the closure to the remote machines, and as such does not run `nix-channel --update` on the remote machines, the Nix Packages Collection (nixpkgs) is not updated on the remote machines.

Commands such as `nix-env` and `nix-shell` rely on the `nixpkgs` pointed to by `$NIX_PATH` (or whichever path you provide via the `-I` argument).

### Solution

The solution is to get your version of `nixpkgs` into the remote machines and ensure `$NIX_PATH` points to it. By default, `$NIX_PATH` looks like this:

```
nixpkgs=/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos/nixpkgs:nixos-config=/etc/nixos/configuration.nix:/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels
```

So the idea is to make it look like something like this:

```
nixpkgs=/nix/store/blah-blah-blah:nixos-config=/etc/nixos/configuration.nix:/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels
```

where *blah-blah-blah* is your `nixpkgs` Git repo inserted into the Nix store. Here's an example of how to do that:

```
let
    # This will point to whatever NIX_PATH states on the local machine,
    # unless overwritten with -I.
    hostNixpkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};

    # Some other nixpkgs from a GitHub repo
    romildo = hostNixpkgs.pkgs.fetchFromGitHub {
         owner = "romildo";
         repo = "nixpkgs";
         rev = "b167ba35987c2e69dc1bb91d5c245a04421ee7ed";
         sha256 = "02d8dfvginz45h2zhq745kynzygnsy760qh7yy152wpfhczag180";
    };
in
{
    network.description = "My NixOS VMs";

    vm0 = { config, lib, pkgs, ... }:
    {
      ...

      # This is really hacky, but it works.
      # I'd prefer to set environment.etc.NIX_PATH, but that's not allowed,
      # because that value is "read-only".
      environment.extraInit = "export NIX_PATH=nixpkgs=${romildo}:nixos-config=/etc/nixos/configuration.nix:/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels";
    };
}
```

### How it works

Nix creates `/nix/store/BLAH-set-environment` which exports a bunch of environment variables, among other things. This file is made available in all shell sessions. `environment.extraInit` makes it possible to append whatever shell-neutral (sh) code you want to this environment. Because this arbitrary code is inserted at the end of the script, it can be used to override the environment variables, such as `NIX_PATH`.

The caveat is that you must log back in after deployment in order for the change to take affect. But the resulting `NIX_PATH` will look something like this: `nixpkgs=/nix/store/mzxkszfv05np2f6rgdi2kwxd937f0sxa-source:nixos-config=/etc/nixos/configuration.nix:/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels`. So in this example, `nix-shell` will look for `nixpkgs` at `/nix/store/mzxkszfv05np2f6rgdi2kwxd937f0sxa-source`.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer! I wonder wether there is a way where I don't need to change the rev/sha256 everytime I update my Nixpkgs.

Comment: What *might* work is using the absolute path to whatever `<nixpkgs>` is supposed to be, instead of using `romildo = hostNixpkgs.pkgs.fetchFromGitHub...`. Ex. `romildo = /my/custom/nixpkgs;` What I know doesn't work is `hostNixpkgs = <nixpkgs>;` nor `hostNixpkgs = builtins.toPath <nixpkgs>;`. The latter produces a `path` type, but for some reason Nix doesn't insert the content into the Nix store, so it bombs.

Answer (score 0):

Set this in `configuration.nix` (or however you structure your configuration):

```
{
  nix.nixPath = [ "nixpkgs=${pkgs.path}:/other/custom/paths/you/need" ];
}
```